# How can I get a button to execute a PHP function without reloading the page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function, variables

I'm a high school student working on a school ICT project, so I'm pretty much new to PHP and Ajax. I'm trying to set up a PHP page where, when a button is clicked, a new, correct maths sum is generated. I can generate a random sum every time I reload a page, and I can use a button to change text within a  using Ajax, but I want to use the Ajax button to generate a new sum without reloading the page, as I intend to use the website as a web-based app later on, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

I've looked on W3Schools' website, but I couldn't find anything that combines the two.

This is the code for the button that changes text:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "/ajaxtest.php", success: function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"><h2>Testing Button</h2></div>
    <button>boom</button>
    </body>
```

This is the PHP function that generates a new sum (the minimum result of the equation is 2 and the maximum is 20):

```
<?php
    $min = 1;
    $max = 10;
    $a = mt_rand($min, $max);
    $b = mt_rand($min, $max);

function sum(int $x, int $y) {
    $answer = $x + $y;
    return $answer;
}

echo "$a + $b = " . sum($a,$b) . "<br>";

echo $answer;
?>
```

ajaxtest.php merely contains text that changes the text in div1. I've tried pasting the function into this file, but it doesn't do anything.

When the button is clicked, I expect a new equation to be generated which replaces the text in div1, e.g. 1+2=3, and then, when clicked again, will replace the former equation with a new equation, e.g. 4+5=6. I don't intend to keep the text in div1, just generate numbers in it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code is giving an error ...

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to sum() must be an instance
>   of int, integer given, called in C:\Users\wayne\Desktop\127.0.0.1\New
>   folder\ajax\ajaxtest.php on line 13 and defined in
>   C:\Users\wayne\Desktop\127.0.0.1\New folder\ajax\ajaxtest.php on line
>   8

...

Changing the function to ...

```
function sum( $x, $y) {
    $answer = $x + $y;
    return $answer;
}
```

... removes the error and agrees with your echo, Clearly 1.5 + 2.5 would not be equal to 3.

```
echo "$a + $b = " . sum($a,$b) . "<br>";
```

Update ... BTW the html is working on my machine fine. But having the script at the bottom of the page is the current best practices as the script at the top blocks rendering and reading of any CSS links that may follow.

Since the ajax is async, no need to place it at the top.

Update Another suggestion, which would of solved the problem for you ...

Your development system should not be configured to not report errors, but rather not reporting of errors should be your runtime configuration.

The development system only needs php to be installed, using a shortcut with the properties of ...

C:\PHP\php.exe -S 0.0.0.0:80 -d extension=php_openssl.dll

... launches the PHP development web host. The extension is obviously not needed but may come in useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips on how to improve the code. I also realized that pasting the function code into ajaxtest.php does work... I don't know why it didn't the first time. Perhaps it was the thing about having the script at the top the first time. Again, thanks a lot - it works now!